# java - switch statement with range of int

Tags: java, if-statement, integer, switch-statement, range

I want to use a switch statement to check a range of numbers I have found a few places saying something like
`case 1...5` or `case (score >= 120) && (score <=125)` would work but I just somehow keep on getting errors.

What I want is if the number is between 1600-1699 then do something.

I can do if statements but figured it's time to start using switch if possible.

Comment: There are times for an 'if', and there are times for a 'switch'. *This* is a time for an 'if'.

Answer (score 13):

**On the JVM level `switch` statement is fundamentally different from if statements.**

Switch is about compile time constants that have to be all specified at compile time, so that javac compiler produces efficient bytecode.

**In Java `switch` statement does not support ranges.** You have to specify all the values (you might take advantage of falling through the cases) and `default` case. Anything else has to be handled by `if` statements.

Answer (score 8):

If you *really* want to use switch statements — here is a way to create pseudo-ranges with `enum`s, so you can switch over the enums.

First, we'll need to create the ranges:

```java
public enum Range {
        
    TWO_HUNDRED(200, 299),
    SIXTEEN_HUNDRED(1600, 1699),
    OTHER(0, -1); // This range can never exist, but it is necessary
                  // in order to prevent a NullPointerException from
                  // being thrown while we switch
        
    private final int minValue;
    private final int maxValue;
        
    private Range(int min, int max) {
        this.minValue = min;
        this.maxValue = max;
    }
        
    public static Range from(int score) {
        return Arrays.stream(Range.values())
            .filter(range -> score >= range.minValue && score <= range.maxValue)
            .findAny()
            .orElse(OTHER);
    }
}
```

And then your switch:

```java
int num = 1630;
switch (Range.from(num)) {

    case TWO_HUNDRED:
        // Do something
        break;

    case SIXTEEN_HUNDRED:
        // Do another thing
        break;

    case OTHER:
    default:
        // Do a whole different thing
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use ternary operator, `? :`

```
int num = (score >= 120) && (score <=125) ? 1 : -1;
num = (score >= 1600) && (score <=1699 ) ? 2 : num;
switch (num) {
    case 1 :
       break;
    case 2 :
       break;
    default :
      //for -1
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, ranges aren't possible for switch cases in Java. You can do something like

```
switch (num) {
  case 1: case 2: case 3:
    //stuff
    break;
  case 4: case 5: case 6: 
    //more stuff
    break;
  default:
}
```

But at that point, you might as well stick with the if statement.